# Google Maps API V3 custom control sizes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Question -----
Is there a way to reference the size of default controls in the Google Maps API V3?

Background -----
I have a webapp that uses the Google Maps API (V3) for several mapping functions.  The primary function is a location search with an advanced filter.  I've added functions to handle two custom controls that I've positioned just below the +/- small zoom controls in the top-left side.  The custom controls themselves work fine - one turns the user's current location on/off, and the other lets users draw a circle to define the search point and range/radius.

I'd like to make these custom controls look as consistent to the standard controls (namely the +/- small zoom controls) as I can.  I think they look okay except for the size, which can vary wildly from the size of the standard controls.  I've read that the API automatically sizes the standard controls used based on the type of device and screen size.  While I appreciate that, I'd like to be able to make the size of my buttons the same as those.

I can provide screen clips if helpful (can't post yet until I build some rep points).  Has anyone else dealt with this and figured out how to reference the standard controls in order to properly size custom controls?

Comment: So you're trying to figure out how to resize your controls the same way google resizes it's controls?

Comment: Precisely, either by some screen size switch-casing (and trial-and-error), or finding the width of the zoom buttons to match.